# CiviCRM's PayPal - Website Payments Pro no longer supported for new PayPal business customers

Tags: payment-processor, paypal

I have installed CiviCRM (5.50.1) on WordPress (6.0) for an Australian Not-For-Profit (NFP). The NFP has an existing PayPal Business account for credit card payments used with a PayPal button-based shopping-cart .

CiviCRM contribution pages using CiviCRM's *PayPal – Website Payments Pro* payment processor have been successfully tested with the NFP's PayPal sandbox accounts.

CiviCRM returned this error message after I swapped in the live payment API signature from [View or remove API signature](https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/mytools/apiaccess/firstparty/signature):

> “Payment Processor Error message: Invalid Configuration This transaction cannot be processed. The merchant's account is not able to process transactions.”

The CiviCRM System Administrator Guide [Enable Website Payments Pro for Your Sandbox Account](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/paypal-pro/#enable-website-payments-pro-for-your-sandbox-account) says that I should be able to click on *Apply for Website Payments Pro* in the PayPal account and notes:

> “You will get an error message from the PayPal Payments server if you attempt to do a direct (Website Payments Pro style) transaction before your account is approved.”

Fair enough, but I can't find an *Apply for Website Payments Pro* link in the NFP's PayPal account and PayPal's [Website Payments Pro](https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/payflow/website-payments-pro/) page says:

> “PayPal isn't accepting new users for this feature, and we require existing users to upgrade to our Advanced Debit and Credit solution”.

The links on this page lead me down an SDK rabbit hole, and it's not clear how to upgrade an existing account.

Will the PayPal account's live SOAP API signature work with CiviCRM's *PayPal – Website Payments Pro* payment processor if I upgrade to Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments?

If so, where on PayPal's site do I apply for Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments for an existing account?

Comment: I use the PayPal Checkout integration in the excellent CiviCRM OmniPay extension (https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.omnipaymultiprocessor) but I see a link to request Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments in my PayPal Developer account:  https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate. I hope that's what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your response Mark. I have substituted the PayPal Checkout integration in place of Website Payments Pro. It's a much poorer user experience for credit/debit card transactions. In particular,  the PayPal pop-up window automatically defaults to "Save information & create your PayPal account", which in turns requires a date of birth. The payee can turn it off, but it's a step that makes the payment process much more complicated.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I made some changes to filter out unwanted PayPal options. The default button for paying by card actually forces an account creation. At least, that's the behavior in my region (US). Many of my donors will not do so. They are also presented with a button for PayPal Credit, which no donor has ever used -- we have recurring donations enabled so there is no reason to finance a payment plan! Anyway, I filtered those options so the donor is presented with a single button marked "PayPal" that offers login or guest checkout. If you are interested, I will share my changes.

Comment: Hi Mark, I would be interested in those changes - we are expecting significant member/donor pushback about the complexity of the PayPal pop-up form.

Comment: In Metadata/js/omnipay_PaypalRest.js:  

`88c88
<   var paypalScriptURL = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=' + CRM.vars.omnipay.client_id + '&currency=' + CRM.vars.omnipay.currency + '&commit=false&vault=true&disable-funding=credit,card';
---
>   var paypalScriptURL = 'https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=' + CRM.vars.omnipay.client_id + '&currency=' + CRM.vars.omnipay.currency + '&commit=false&vault=true';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have received advice from PayPal Merchant Technical Support that it is long longer possible to apply for Website Payments Pro, and that access to Advanced Credit and Debit Card Payments will not provide access to the SOAP API used by Payments Pro, so for new CiviCRM users, PayPal Website Payments Pro is no longer an option as a payment provider